# Can I use class_weight in keras model in Tensorflow Federated Learning (TFF)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

My dataset is class imbalanced, so I want to use class_weight which enables the classifier heavily weight minor class. In general setting, I can assign class weight as below:

```py
weighted_history = weighted_model.fit(
    train_features,
    train_labels,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
    validation_data=(val_features, val_labels),
    # The class weights go here
    class_weight=class_weight)
```

Is there any way that I can assign class_weight in tensorflow federated learning? My code for federated learning is below:

```py
def create_keras_model(output_bias=None):
    return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='relu', input_shape(5,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])

def model_fn():
    keras_model = create_keras_model()
    return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
        keras_model,
        input_spec=preprocessed_example_dataset.element_spec,
        loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
        metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. The main problem is that `tf.keras.Model.fit` method does not conceptually map onto the idea of training from decentralized data.

If you want to make this work in `TFF`, the first step is to determine what is the algorithm that should be executed. This does not have an obvious answer as far as I can see -- for example, how do you determine what are those `class_weights` if you don't have direct access to the data?

But let's assume that you have that information somehow available and simply want to modify the local training procedure at clients. Starting from [`examples/simple_fedavg`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg), the way to make it happen would be to appropriately modify how gradients are computed in [this loop](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/53eb79a80f12decc3e5d439164735aec9fe9f52a/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L210).

Comment: Thank you for your good point. How would you evaluate the FL model? I am comparing the model with server-based model (same keras model). Should I randomly select same number of clients from test set or should I use the whole test set?